# c# creating an IAM user on AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-iam

I have the requirements to create an IAM user programmatically in AWS.

Unfortunately all of the examples I have found online require the nuget package AWSSDK.

The AWSSDK package is deprecated and I do not want to use something that should be updated.

Does anyone have any links or examples of creating an IAM user using AWSSDK.Core or AWSSDK.IdentityManagement?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install NuGet package: AWSSDK.IdentityManagement

```
        var identityService = new AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey"));
        var createUserRequest = new CreateUserRequest
                                {
                                    UserName = "newUsername",
                                };
        var createUserResponse = identityService.CreateUser(createUserRequest);
        var createdUser = createUserResponse.User;
```